What are the differences between requests via Node's fetch() and requests via browsers?
I'm trying to scrape some APIs for public data. I'm sometimes getting blocked when using Node's fetch, but I'm not blocked when requesting the same API using my browser. Usually, if I'm blocked, I'd assume it's an IP ban. But on Chrome Incognito on the same IP with no cookies, I'm not blocked. This happens for Instagram's API and Reddit's API.
From the receiving server's perspective, what are some differences between a request made via Node's fetch and requests made via Chrome? E.g. I know one difference is Chrome sometimes adds the header "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate", but for Node's fetch, it's always "sec-fetch-mode": "cors". Instagram's API uses "sec-fetch-mode": "cors" anyway, so that shouldn't be the difference. What are some other underlying differences between browser and Node requests?
Here's the request via Chrome's "Copy as fetch (Node.js)":
fetch("https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=[removed]", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "priority": "u=1, i",
    "sec-ch-prefers-color-scheme": "light",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"124\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"124\", \"Not-A.Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-full-version-list": "\"Chromium\";v=\"124.0.6367.91\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"124.0.6367.91\", \"Not-A.Brand\";v=\"99.0.0.0\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-model": "\"\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform-version": "\"15.0.0\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-asbd-id": "129477",
    "x-csrftoken": "[removed]",
    "x-ig-app-id": "936619743392459",
    "x-ig-www-claim": "0",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "x-web-device-id": "[removed]",
    "cookie": "csrftoken=[removed]",
    "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/[removed]/",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  },
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET"
}).then(res => res.text()).then(console.log);


"Blocked" meaning what exactly? "Blocked" how?

Node's native fetch has a hardcoded user agent. This is the most obvious difference that can be used to blacklist the requests. node-fetch supports custom user agent. Also in a real browser there are cookies for each session even in incognito, they are used in subsequent requests

NodeJS' HTTP engine and a web browser use entirely different HTTP libraries thus the website can clearly differentiate between these two types of request.
The difference list is too big for a stackoverflow questions but to summarize it it's the entire HTTP and TLS implementation not only headers as your question implies. This is generally referred to as TLS fingerprint and HTTP fingerprint and the only way to get around them is to use an actual browser or a patched headless web browser like undetected-chromedriver

I've covered this topic more in-depth on my blog previously if you're interested in learning how exactly it's being done but nodejs bypass is unlikely to happen. See how scraper blocking works
